# XSLT Component template transformation with external images

Tags: templating, xslt

We have Multimedia Component that works with external and internal images. When we have external images we have two cases:

- External Image that has query string parametes ...
  ex: `http://yahoo.com/someimage.jpg?param1=1&param2=2&+_+=.jpg`
- External Image that has no query string parameters ... 
  ex: `http://yahoo.com/someimage.jpg`

In our component template transformation we would like to display the second type the way it is stored, and the first one we would like to be: `http://yahoo.com/someimage.jpg?param1=1&param2=2`

The code looks like:

```
<xsl:if test="document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:IsExternalMultimediaFile = 'true' and contains(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=') = 'false'">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<Image>]]></xsl:text>
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<img src="]]></xsl:text>

   <xsl:value-of select="document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename" />        

  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" alt="]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:title" />
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA["  />]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</Image>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:IsExternalMultimediaFile = 'true' and contains(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=') = 'true'">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<Image>]]></xsl:text>
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<img src="]]></xsl:text>      

   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=')" />      

  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" alt="]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:title" />
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA["  />]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</Image>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

For some reason both the cases get executed. Can someone help? The solution is probably only a error in the if  but I am not sure where...

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion both cases get executed?

Comment: the image appears on the page twice and this is how the transformed code look like...   <Image>
          <img src="http://cdn.hw.net/UploadService/1c8b7f28-bb12-4e02-b888-388fdff5836e.jpg?w=160&amp;h=120&amp;mode=crop&amp;404=default&amp;+_+=.jpg" alt="External-img-no-ext"  />
        </Image>
        <Image>
          <img src="http://cdn.hw.net/UploadService/1c8b7f28-bb12-4e02-b888-388fdff5836e.jpg?w=160&amp;h=120&amp;mode=crop&amp;404=default" alt="External-img-no-ext"  />
        </Image>

Comment: Initially I tried without using the if statement but substring-before returned null if the string was not found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is indeed "an error in the if". You have used the XPath 'contains' function, which returns a boolean, and then compared it with a string (either 'true' or 'false'). In the case of comparing a boolean to a string, the string is [converted to a boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean).

The rules for this conversion are that a non-empty string is true, and an empty string is false, so 'true' and 'false' both evaluate to true. To demonstrate this, try running this XSLT against a document of your choice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="contains('foo','oo') = 'true'">
      Foo contains oo "equals" 'true'
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('foo','oo') = 'false'">
      Foo contains oo "equals" 'false'
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
Foo contains oo "equals" 'true'      
Foo contains oo "equals" 'false'
```

For this kind of test, you are better off just using the boolean value returned by `contains()`, or of course if you want the opposite, you can use the `not()` function.

Comment: Dominic, this is a great explanation of what was wrong with Kremena's XSLT.

Comment: I think you are very right. I tried it too and am not sure why in our case it works typecasted to string when I have only one confition in the if, but when I add AND (second condition) it does not...

Comment: Your first condition compares a string with a string. That's fine. The second condition compares a boolean to a string, which forces the string to be evaluated as a boolean.

Answer (score 8):

You should better follow my XSLT, since the way you declared is not the right approach.

```
    <xsl:if test="document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:IsExternalMultimediaFile = 'true'">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=') = 'false'">
                <xsl:element name="Image">
                    <xsl:element name="img">
                        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:title"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=') = 'true'">
                <xsl:element name="Image">
                    <xsl:element name="img">
                        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=')"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:title"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thank you Siva. I was just about to answer my own question with the same answer.

Comment: I used <xsl:otherwise> instead of the second when but believe that it is the same output.

Comment: @KremenaLalova: Never it will be same. If you feel it is coming twice then you are passing the same field twice or two different fields which has `IsExternalMultimediaFile='true'` and URL matches with `contains`

Comment: Oh yes deffinately. What I meant was that instead of <xsl:when test="contains(document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:MultimediaFilename, '&amp;+_+=') = 'true'">
I used <xsl:otherwise> and since otherwise of false is true or null it worked the same way.

Comment: @KremenaLalova: In your case, don't try with otherwise and this will execute always if the first condition fails. Have tried the one which I have given?

Comment: Yes I tried your example and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @SivaCharan if you are performing a simple bolean test in a when clause like this (the substring is either in the string or it is not) it should be safe to use the `<xsl:otherwise>` to catch the items that don't match the first condition. There is a course a risk here if you later update the first condition you could wind up with unintended side affects of using the otherwise like this.

Comment: @SivaCharan, +1 for the helpful answer. It might also help other readers to understand what's *wrong* with the posted approach (in a nice way of course). One other alternative with XSLT is to do a template match for certain scenarios (e.g. `<template match="some_xpath">`). The conditional tests work, but might miss a chance to recursively "apply-templates" for additional transformations.

Comment: @KremenaLalova, do notice Siva's `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attirbute>` approach which makes for easier to read/maintain XSLT.

Answer (score 4):

Consider matching on just the `img/@href` as well as using variables to help manage this requirement, especially if you're already using an ["identity" XSLT approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

Dominic's example helps clarify how XSLT handles string and boolean comparisons; XSL variables can help isolate, test, and mange your logic. Siva shows how to simplify writing out the XML nodes and points out when not to use `otherwise.` This approach might make updates easier as well as keep the ability match on specific nodes and attributes independently.

### Matching on just image/@href

Note: when matching an attribute directly, you can use `document(.)`.

```xml
<xsl:variable name="Pattern" select="'&amp;+_+='" />
...
<xsl:template match="xhtml:img/@xlink:href">

<!-- optional shortcuts for the Data path, boolean checks, and strings -->    
<xsl:variable name="ImageData" select="document(.)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data" />
<xsl:variable name="IsExternal" select="$ImageData/tcm:IsExternalMultimediaFile" />
<xsl:variable name="FileName" select="$ImageData/tcm:MultimediaFilename" />
<xsl:variable name="IncludesPattern" select="contains($FileName, $Pattern)" />

<xsl:variable name="ModifiedName">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$IsExternal and $IncludesPattern">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($FileName, $Pattern)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$FileName" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$ModifiedName" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

### Testing `img`

To double-check the logic and inspect details from the `img` node level, use something like the following (temporarily).

```xml
<xsl:template match="xhtml:img">
<xsl:variable name="ImageData" select="document(@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data" />
<xsl:variable name="IsExternal" select="$ImageData/tcm:IsExternalMultimediaFile" />
<xsl:variable name="FileName" select="$ImageData/tcm:MultimediaFilename" />
<xsl:variable name="IncludesPattern" select="contains($FileName, $Pattern)" />
<xsl:variable name="TrimmedPath" select="substring-before($FileName, $Pattern)" />

<xsl:comment>IsExternal: <xsl:value-of select="$IsExternal" />,
FileName: <xsl:value-of select="$FileName" />,
IncludesPattern: <xsl:value-of select="$IncludesPattern" />
</xsl:comment>

<img>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</img>
```

But when you're done testing, just use the basic identity templates if you're not already doing so.

### Identity Example

**Remove namespaces:**

```xml
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Basic copy:**

```xml
<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```